# Can't open Telnet from Windows 10 PowerShell

Tags: powershell, telnet

It's enabled, but Telnet wont open:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had to add %windir%\sysnative\ to environment variables path. Its a 32/64 bit issue. [Link to source.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSHTQ_8.1.0/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_8.1.0/webtop/wip/task/web_con_telnettrouble.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
install-windowsfeature "telnet-client"
```

You should be table to type telnet and Telnet Client should open.

Comment: I agree, but its not working.

Comment: You run get-windowsfeature and it shows its installed?

Comment: I did, yes, it is definitely installed.